# Ubuntu 16.04 Ethernet & Wifi don't work after downgrading kernel from 4.10 to 4.4

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I use Acer 5750G. I need to use a special software which is only working on kernel 4.4 with network. So I downgraded the kernel. Booting is success exclude network. I have no idea to fix it. Please help.

I don't found my ethernet driver tg3.ko and wireless driver ath9k.ko on 4.4 but 4.10.

Here is some info. Hope would help. [by  varunendra](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12350385#post12350385)

Result on 4.4

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Nov 2017 14:41 CST +0800

Booted last: 23 Nov 2017 00:00 CST +0800

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-98-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 14:24:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu (from ~/.dmrc)

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:0504]

02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H167.00 [105b:e034]
    Kernel modules: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:b002 Alcor Micro Corp. Acer Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:133288 (133.2 KB)  TX bytes:133288 (133.2 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       907     1  0 14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ISNET]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ISNET | type=wifi | permissions=user:justin:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ISNET
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

nl80211 not found.

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    7.233292] systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
[   15.154259] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   15.156037] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   15.156163] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err 0)
[   15.156171] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err 0)
[   15.156205] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err 0)
[   15.156217] wl: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err 0)
[   15.156233] wl: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_frequency (err 0)
[   15.156245] wl: Unknown symbol ieee80211_frequency_to_channel (err 0)
[   15.156251] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err 0)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious what is this special software. Anyway, what happened clearly means that your wifi drivers were added somewhere after linux-4.4. If you're really eager to run 4.4, you can find which was the first kernel with driver, and try loading the driver with `insmod`. It may not work as expected due to interface changes between kernel and drivers — it's the reason linux kernel despite being 26 years old still modern, i.e. because kernel often being refactored through the core and drivers. In this case you have to download sources, manually port the driver to 4.4, and build the kernel.

You can use [this link](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions) for a nice list of changes between kernels, hopefully it might be enough to figure out where the driver was added.